# Is there a database of worldwide transcripts of political debates and speeches?

Tags: politics

Is there a database of worldwide transcripts of political debates and speeches? I wanted to it to build a model to predict elections. I would also like worldwide political candidate polling data.

Comment: I closed this as duplicate of the US election speeches question. If you better explain what you mean by "worldwide", and why the resources in the US election answers aren't relevant, then we can re-open.